# How to change link of main logo to custom URLs instead of homepage, with WordPress Avada child theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, customization

I am trying to change the logo link for specific pages, so that it will link to a custom URL for specific page.

I tried to add this code that I found also here in stackoverflow. This works fine on page "169" the logo link point to https://sampleurl.com/page-1/.

```
//This is for page-1
add_filter('avada_logo_anchor_tag_attributes', 'broadway_logo_link_modify');
function broadway_logo_link_modify() {

  $link = esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );

  if (is_page( array (169))) {
    $link = 'https://sampleurl.com/page-1/';
  }

  // another option with which you don't have to add every page id
  $current_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  if (strpos($current_url, 'https://sampleurl.com/page-1/') !== false) {
    $link = 'https://sampleurl.com/page-1/';
  }

  $link_arr = array(
    'class' => 'fusion-logo-link',
    'href' => $link,
  );

  return $link_arr;

}

//This is for page-2
add_filter('avada_logo_anchor_tag_attributes', 'broadway_logo_link_modify');
function broadway_logo_link_modify() {

  $link = esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );

  if (is_page( array (169))) {
    $link = 'https://sampleurl.com/page-2/';
  }

  // another option with which you don't have to add every page id
  $current_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  if (strpos($current_url, 'https://sampleurl.com/page-2/') !== false) {
    $link = 'https://sampleurl.com/page-2/';
  }

  $link_arr = array(
    'class' => 'fusion-logo-link',
    'href' => $link,
  );

  return $link_arr;

}
```

I am trying to add the url for /page-2 and /page-3. I added the code again and change the URL to https://sampleurl.com/page-2/ but it broke the site "HTTP Error".

Anyone knows what's the right code to add? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please change the second function name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you are using same function name for both function at that time same function name declaration will cause php error. For avoiding that problem you can rename the second function name like as following code.

```
//This is for page-1
add_filter('avada_logo_anchor_tag_attributes', 'broadway_logo_link_modify1');
function broadway_logo_link_modify1() {

  $link = esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );

  if (is_page( array (169))) {
    $link = 'https://sampleurl.com/page-1/';
  }

  // another option with which you don't have to add every page id
  $current_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  if (strpos($current_url, 'https://sampleurl.com/page-1/') !== false) {
    $link = 'https://sampleurl.com/page-1/';
  }

  $link_arr = array(
    'class' => 'fusion-logo-link',
    'href' => $link,
  );

  return $link_arr;

}

//This is for page-2
add_filter('avada_logo_anchor_tag_attributes', 'broadway_logo_link_modify2');
function broadway_logo_link_modify2() {

  $link = esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );

  if (is_page( array (210))) {
    $link = 'https://sampleurl.com/page-2/';
  }

  // another option with which you don't have to add every page id
  $current_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  if (strpos($current_url, 'https://sampleurl.com/page-2/') !== false) {
    $link = 'https://sampleurl.com/page-2/';
  }

  $link_arr = array(
    'class' => 'fusion-logo-link',
    'href' => $link,
  );

  return $link_arr;

}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback. I changed the function name, the link for page 2 is working fine but for page 1 it links back to homepage...Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Copy that I understand...Thanks for the help